# Method 'references' not found in Illuminate\Support\Fluent in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.8 with PHP 7.1
It gives the warning with the references() function.

```
$table->foreign('student_id')->references('student_id')->on('student');
```

The error is:

```
Warning:(52, 45) Method 'references' not found in Illuminate\Support\Fluent
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have checked the official documentation if the function is deprecated. But it's still there in 5.8 version

Comment: can you include your full code please

Comment: You say error but your message says `Warning`, which one is it? Does the code not work at all or is your IDE just complaining?

Comment: Yeah. my PhpStorm is not recognising the function only.

Comment: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper#automatic-phpdocs-generation-for-laravel-fluent-methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's your IDE complaining not a laravel issue. Add this code to the top of your `_ide_helper.php` file.

```
namespace Illuminate\Support{
/**
 * @method Fluent first()
 * @method Fluent after($column)
 * @method Fluent change()
 * @method Fluent nullable()
 * @method Fluent unsigned()
 * @method Fluent unique()
 * @method Fluent index()
 * @method Fluent primary()
 * @method Fluent default($value)
 * @method Fluent onUpdate($value)
 * @method Fluent onDelete($value)
 * @method Fluent references($value)
 * @method Fluent on($value)
 */
class Fluent {}
}
```

Your issue should be fixed after this

Comment: What IDE is this file for?

Comment: This is for PHP storm